Can a press release have a positive impact on website SEO in 2024?
I have the option of issuing an important press-release to the Canadian market in the next month and was wondering if this might have the potential to have a positive impact on my website SEO.
The press-release in question refers to the acquisition of a well-known Canadian company, so it will hopefully be of interest to news outlets publishing business and financial content.
I understand that the SEO value of traditional press-release distribution services has declined immensely over the past decade for multiple reasons, so I am wondering if press-releases in 2024 are now useless for SEO or if they can still have a positive impact when done properly.

Press release helps you to improve your brands, digital brand awareness. You can also receive "Dofollow" backlinks but most of the PR sites gives you "Nofollow" only.
You can go for the PR and PR syndication if there is any news that you want to share with your audience, it could be new product laugh, new leadership or something helpful that your customers or clients should know.
I've witnessed positive impacts in terms of brand awareness and visibility, as a results organic and direct traffic got increased too.
PR will never die until there are digital news media over there. Additionally, these PR news ranks in Google and Google News.
I hope this helped you.
